# git merge everything except one directory

Tags: git, github, terminal, osx-mavericks

I want to git merge everything except one directory. So I am thinking of doing

```
git add --all .
git reset /bad_directory/*
git commit -m "commit message"
git pull my_project master
git push my_project master
```

Is this correct? Of course I am asking because I don't want to execute this and end up screwing things up worse. Thanks.

Comment: You're asking about "merging", but nowhere do you suggest using `git merge`. Please clarify *exactly* what you want to do, including any relevant branch names.

Comment: I mean pull then push: that's how I like to merge. Perhaps a misuse of the term, but I mean `pull-then-push`. The main concerned of course being the `bad_directory`: I want to leave it out.

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to not add the "bad_directory" to your commit, then commit all other files, then stash your changes in the "bad_directory" if you want to maintain them for later:

```
git add #{list of files to add}
git commit -m "commit message"
git stash
git pull origin master # consider doing a --rebase here
git push origin master
```

You should read up on git-stash, but later you can pop or just throw away the contents of the stash.

The problem with git-reset is I assume you will want to do a git-reset --hard, and you cannot do that on a subdirectory.

Comment: `git add #{list of files to add}` would be ungodly. Which is why I am hoping for a command that would allow me to exclude one directory.

Comment: then just do `git add -A` then followed by `git rm --cached -r bad_dir`

Comment: The ~`git add -A .;git reset bad-dir`~ in the question might be right for what he wants, the effects are right for a lot of situations I could imagine. Whatever's right for the situationin bad-dir, it seems to me the stash/stash pop pair you've got here is the important part, that that's what addresses OP's question.  I might add a reminder that stash pop is a merge, that seems to surprise a lot of people.

Comment: agreed that `git-stash` is the important part of the workflow and allows for you to merge to your local repo without having to merge those files, which I assume was the point of doing the reset in the first place, there are so many ways to accomplish the same thing in different ways.